# OpenCart - Static discount percent

Tags: opencart, discount

I've added some discount percent extension on the opencart 1.5.4.1 and it works, if i add the percent, the product price with discount updates automatically.

But if i update the original price of the product, the value with discount doesn't changes by the percent, it stays the same and the percent changes based on the original price.

Is it possible to make the price with disconut dymanic based on the percent, independent of the original price?